# Deserialize Json String to C# object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.ios, deserialization

I'm trying out the Philips Hue lights api for the first time and I have a few questions on how to deserialize the json string to a C# object. I'm trying this out for the Xamarin.iOS app I'm working on.

Here's my method that would fetch the light data from around me:

```
private string getLights()
{
    var url = APIURL + APIKey + LightsEndPoint ; 

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(
                "Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}",
                response.StatusCode);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Light> (content);            
            }
            return content; 
        }
    }
}
```

Where Light is:

```
public class Light
{
    public Light()
    { }

    public string LightName { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string IsOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sat")]
    public int Saturation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bri")]
    public int Brightness {get;set;} 

    [JsonProperty("hue")]
    public int Hue { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm having now is my items object is always empty, null values even though I'm properly getting content json string.

My json string looks like this:

```
{  
    "1":{  
        "state":{  
            "on":true,
            "bri":254,
            "hue":20000,
            "sat":100,
            "effect":"none",
            "xy":[  
                 0.4146,
                 0.4155
            ],
            "ct":299,
            "alert":"none",
            "colormode":"hs",
            "reachable":true
        },
        "type":"Extended color light",
        "name":"Hue color lamp 1",
        "modelid":"LCT007",
        "manufacturername":"Philips",
        "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:10:26:3f:12-0b",
        "swversion":"5.38.1.14919"
    },
    "2":{  
        "state":{  
            "on":false,
            "bri":254,
            "hue":50000,
            "sat":254,
            "effect":"none",
            "xy":[  
                0.2468,
                0.0843
            ],
            "ct":153,
            "alert":"none",
            "colormode":"hs",
            "reachable":true
        },
        "type":"Extended color light",
        "name":"Hue color lamp 2",
        "modelid":"LCT007",
        "manufacturername":"Philips",
        "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:10:5d:fd:f6-0b",
        "swversion":"5.38.1.14919"
    },
    "3":{  
        "state":{  
            "on":true,
            "bri":254,
            "hue":10000,
            "sat":254,
            "effect":"none",
            "xy":[  
                0.5711,
                0.3986
            ],
            "ct":500,
            "alert":"none",
            "colormode":"hs",
            "reachable":true
        },
        "type":"Extended color light",
        "name":"Hue color lamp 3",
        "modelid":"LCT007",
        "manufacturername":"Philips",
        "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:10:26:3d:17-0b",
        "swversion":"5.38.1.14919"
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is light is indicated by a numerical value and I'm not sure how to split the json string to populate my c# object.

Basically, I'm having issues converting the json string to c# object for api stream for Xamarin.iOS app.

Comment: It seems you're getting back a dictionary, try deserializing into `Dictionary<string, Light>`.

Comment: Your model does not match with json structure, there are nested properties in json which you declare in your model's root. To be able to deserialize from json your model need to have same structure as json

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I get this error when I try that: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '1.state', line 1, position 15.

Comment: @RubenVardanyan How do I make it match the json structure? I only want the values I specify in my model. Thanks!

Comment: @Euridice01 see the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model should look like this

```
public class Light
{

    public Light()
    {

    }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string LightName { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public class State 
{
    public State() 
    {
    }

    [JsonProperty("on")]
    public bool IsOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sat")]
    public int Saturation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bri")]
    public int Brightness {get;set;} 

    [JsonProperty("hue")]
    public int Hue { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialization call should look like this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Light>>(content);
```

Where the key of the dictionary is the numbers and value is the light model you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

I generated a class with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
public class State
{
    public bool on { get; set; }
    public int bri { get; set; }
    public int hue { get; set; }
    public int sat { get; set; }
    public string effect { get; set; }
    public List<double> xy { get; set; }
    public int ct { get; set; }
    public string alert { get; set; }
    public string colormode { get; set; }
    public bool reachable { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public State state { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string modelid { get; set; }
    public string manufacturername { get; set; }
    public string uniqueid { get; set; }
    public string swversion { get; set; }
}
```

then I called this code:

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, RootObject>>(json);
```

and the result was this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, your model structure does not match that of the json's. You need to properly nest the properties accordingly. I threw together an example, though certain data types I was unsure of I simply used a string(Which should be fine).

Light.cs

```
public class Light
{
    public string LightName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public State LightState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("modelid")]
    public string ModelId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("manufacturername")]
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uniqueid")]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("swversion")]
    public string SwVersion { get; set; }
}
```

State.cs

```
public class State
{
    [JsonProperty("on")]
    public bool IsOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bri")]
    public int Brightness { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hue")]
    public int Hue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sat")]
    public int Saturation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("effect")]
    public string Effect { get; set; } // Just making it a string for now

    [JsonProperty("xy")]
    public double[] XY { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ct")]
    public int CT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alert")]
    public string Alert { get; set; } // Just making another string for now

    [JsonProperty("colormode")]
    public string ColorMode { get; set; } // Hey, it's another string for now

    [JsonProperty("reachable")]
    public bool Reachable { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialize:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Light>> (content);
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Light> (content);` will not work, because the json is map of keys and the values, where the values are `Light` object

Comment: You, sir, are correct! Ding ding ding! I updated it, thanks ;)